# Como mover un objeto en una determinada direccion

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

Hola quiero crear el efecto de lanzar un objeto, en este caso un circulo que esta dibujado en el `canvas`. El problema es que no entiendo como identificar donde se toco en la pantalla y mover el circulo en esa dirección. Mi idea final seria algo como esa imagen.

Cualquier ayuda sirve. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    public class Juego extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener{

    Paint paint;
    int x, y, radio = 100, velocidadX = 5, velocidadY = 5, tocoY, tocoX;
    boolean mover = false;
    boolean una_vez = true;

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        paint = new Paint();
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),paint);

        if (una_vez == true){
            x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
            y = canvas.getHeight()/2;
            una_vez = false;
        }

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);

        if (mover == true){

                if (x >= canvas.getWidth() - radio) {
                    velocidadX = -5;
                }

                if (x <= radio) {
                    velocidadX = 5;
                }

                if (y >= canvas.getHeight() - radio) {
                    velocidadY = -5;
                }

                if (y <= radio) {
                    velocidadY = 5;
                }

            x = x + velocidadX;
            y = y + velocidadY;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):

                tocoX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                tocoY = (int) motionEvent.getY();

                mover = true;

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres trasladar tu vista hasta una posición donde hagas Touch, como por ejemplo digamos que tienes un círculo en la pantalla y tocas una parte de la pantalla y el circulo vaya a esa posición es muy fácil. Mantener dicho círculo presionado y moverlo junto con tu dedo a cualquier parte de la pantalla o hacer que solo se mueva a direcciones horizontales y verticales (Derecha, izquierda, arriba, abajo) también es muy fácil. El problema está en que se mueva junto con tu dedo "restringido" solo a un ángulo no recto, por ejemplo de forma diagonal. Ahi no podría ayudarte.